# Why does JS computed property grammar allow assignment expression?

Tags: javascript, standards, grammar

The Javascript grammar allows an assignment expression (`AssignmentExpression`) to be used in a computed property name (`ComputedPropertyName`) (see [12.2.6 Object Initializer](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) or [ES 2015 Grammarkdown](https://github.com/rbuckton/grammarkdown/blob/master/grammars/es2015.grammar)):

```
ComputedPropertyName[Yield] :
    `[` AssignmentExpression[In, ?Yield]  `]`
```

This allows one writing e.g:

```
 var data;
 var a= {
          [data="something"]: "x"
        }
```

Why is this useful? Why is not enough having a `ConditionalExpression` instead? It seems as an unnecessary complication to the grammar.

Comment: Why would it complicate the parser? The parser already knows how to parse assignment expressions.

Comment: You are correct in this respect. Still, why accept something too general to be usefull, when a less general element would do quite fine? It makes grammar harder to parse when it is extended in future - e.g. distinguishing between `ComputedPropertyName` and `IndexSignature` in TypeScript is harder because of this.

Comment: OK, I'll bite. Afaics, `IndexSignature` conforms to the syntax `identifier : (string | number)`. An assignment expression cannot start with an identifier followed by a colon, so how can the fact that a computed property name can be an assignment expression conflict with IndexSignature? (I'm aware that I'm using the v1.8 typescript grammar, which may not be up to date. It would be nice if it were updated, since there is no obvious other way to see what the typescript grammar might be. But it doesn't seem like any plausible change would affect my question above.)

Comment: You are correct again. Still, why `AssignmentExpression`? Is there some sensible code (or any code at all) which uses `AssignmentExpression` other than `ConditionalExpression` in this position?

Comment: For the background: I am adapting a JS parser (Esprima) to parse TS. I was surprised by seeing `parseAssignmentExpression` inside of `parseObjectPropertyKey` and it seemed to me it would be easier to handle if the grammar did not allow it here. I was wrong in this respect, but I am still curious - is there any reason to have it this way?

Comment: Otherwise `var a = { [yield 3]: 5 }` would not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it is the reverse of your first thought. There is no need to special-case the kind of expression allowed inside a `ComputedPropertyName`, so the language designers chose to use the "normal" expression, which is an `AssignmentExpression`.

If you look through the EcmaScript grammar, you will see that the only place where `ConditionalExpression` is used is in the definition of `AssignmentExpression`. In this respect, it is similar to all the other expression sub-syntaxes defined in the grammar before `AssignmentExpression`, which are present only to define the operator-precedence order of the grammar. (A practical parser based on operator precedence parsing might not even have anything which corresponds to these various non-terminals.)

Basically, aside from defining operator precedence, there are only two expression non-terminals used in the grammar: `AssignmentExpression` and `Expression`. The difference has to do with the unfortunate C legacy of the [comma operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-comma-operator) (which evaluates and then forgets its first argument). `Expression` is used in contexts in which the comma operator is permitted:

```
Expression: AssignmentExpression
          | Expression ',' AssignmentExpression
```

including almost everywhere an expression is used in a `Statement`. `AssignmentExpression` (and no other Expression subsyntax) is used in contexts in which the `,` indicates a list of expressions: argument lists, array literals, and so on. It would have been very difficult to justify limiting the use of assignment expressions to just one obscure corner of the language, while they are usable in pretty well any other context which allows an expression.

There was actually an argument to make the `ComputedPropertyName` syntax even more permissive, rather than banning the use of the comma operator, since the property access syntax (`MemberExpression '[' Expression ']'`) is one of the many places where the comma operator *is* permitted, although it is practically never used.

Actually writing `array[i, j]` is -- at least IMHO -- bad style, since it's almost certain to confuse naive readers who don't realise that it means the same thing as `array[j]` (unless evaluating `i` has a side-effect). In languages where the comma operator is available (C, C++, EcmaScript, and others), this usage is mostly an obfuscation technique, and StackOverflow contains lots of evidence that the obfuscation works. I'd like to think that only the need to maintain backwards compatibility with obfuscated code has prevented the Comittee from removing the comma operator from the property access syntax.

Since the `ComputedPropertyName` syntax is basically analogous to the property access syntax, one might have expected it to also be `Expression`, rather than `AssignmentExpression`. But apparently the Committee was able to resist the temptation.